# Save two or more images from a frame as a single Image to file

Tags: python, qt, qt5

I am new to QT. I have a `frame` on which both `A4Size` and `extra` are. Each one of them is a Qlabel and I set images to them. Now, I want to save everything found on the `frame` (`A4Size` and `extra`) but I find no way that works through the research I've done (saving everything from the frame to file). Is there a way to save both images (or even more) on the frame as a single image?

```
class Picture(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        self.ui = Ui_Picture()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        self.setFixedSize(1430, 1000)

    def show_image(self):
        if self.ui.A4_sheet.isChecked():
            self.ui.A4Size.setPixmap("all.png")
            self.ui.extra.setPixmap("new.png")
            print("A4")

    def download(self):
        fname, filter = QFileDialog.getSaveFileName(self, 'Save Image')
        self.ui.A4Size.pixmap().save(fname + ".png", "PNG", -1)
        print("saved")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    widget = QtWidgets.QStackedWidget()
    home_screen = MainWindow()
    picture_screen = Picture()
    widget.show()
    widget.addWidget(home_screen)
    widget.addWidget(picture_screen)
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

My code above only saves `A4Size` even though `extra` is right on it.

Thank You.

Comment: You need to learn about `QPainter` and how you can paint with it on `QPixmap`. You need to create a `QPixmap` with the size equal to the union of both your images. Then create a `Paointer` instance for it, paint both images to the pixmap at given positions. Then save the final pixmap to a file. Very simple.

Comment: Okay please. Can you help with a random example of painting different images on one ```QPixmap```. This will be greatly appreciated

Comment: I tried to make and answer, I hope my attempt for python code will work for you, I do not work with Python usually.

Answer (score -1):

You need to draw the two pixmaps into one with `QPainter` and then save it.
I am a C++ programmer, but I will try to write Python code now, I hope it will work for you.

```
source1 = QPixmap("all.png")
source2 = QPixmap("new.png")
# we will put the pixmaps next to each other horizontally
width = source1.width() + source2.width()
height = max(source1.height(), source2.height())
pixmap = QPixmap(width, height)
painter = QPainter(pixmap)
painter.drawPixmap(0, 0, source1)
painter.drawPixmap(source1.width(), 0, source2)
pixmap.save(fname + ".png")
```

Comment: Not working for me

Comment: What does it mean "not working"? Does it throw an error? Or does it just save empty file?